# Django: Multiplication of n Decimal Fields returns result with n*2 decimal places

Tags: python, django, decimal

I'm using django, and I have this model:

```
class CartLine(DeletableModel):
product = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='cart_lines', on_delete=do_nothing)
cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', related_name='lines', on_delete=do_nothing)
quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_('Quantity'))

@property
def total_sum(self):
    return self.product.price * self.quantity

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('Cart Line')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Cart Lines')
```

when I used the property total_sum in the template like `{{ line.product.price }}`, it return the result `300.0000`. even when I tried with the filter tag floatformat like `{{ line.product.price|floatformat:2 }}` it returned the same value, it didn't format it.

so I went to the python shell and tried it, and it returned the same value:

```
>>> cartline.total_sum
Decimal('300.0000')
```

and when I changed the property to:

```
@property
def total_sum(self):
    return self.product.price * self.quantity * self.quantity
```

and tested it in the console:

```
cartline.total_sum
Decimal('900.000000')
```

it's like concatinating the decimal places... how can I fix that or work around that to limit the display to 2 decimal places when I do the multiplication or any other operation?

Comment: The precisions addup. Try: `total_sum.quantize(Decimal("0.01"))` to get two place precision

Comment: @schwobaseggl yeah that worked better, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[schwobaseggl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2390182/schwobaseggl) comment solved my issue, by trying `total_sum.quantize(Decimal("0.01"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `round()` function to make the `total_sum` display the exact decimal places you want.

Something like this:

```
@property
def total_sum(self):
    return round(Decimal(self.product.price * self.quantity), 2)
```